# What is the best combination of muscle groups to workout together?

Tags: exercise, strength, muscle

I have not exercised properly in about a few years and I'm dying to get back into it.

I've put together the following routine :

**Monday**: Leg Day and Abs

**Tuesday**: Chest

**Wednesday**: Back and Abs

**Thursday**: Shoulders

**Friday**: Biceps, Triceps and Abs

Is there any benefit to working out certain muscle groups together? Should I change or rearrange these exercises?

Comment: Swap out your whole routine for starting strength or stronglifts 5x5. Safer, more effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routine seems fine to me, its a matter of personal preference though. The key is to keep it short. Have lesser rest period (30-45 secs max). And consistently increase weight. It certainly helps doing compound routines rather than working on individual muscle groups. But there are some routines which mostly do not involve other muscle groups (biceps for example). And don't keep repeating the same routines each time you work on a muscle group. Try something different or a different combinations each time you workout. Diet, rest and sleep also will help you immensely to reach to the peak that you have set.
As long as you are focused, determined, consistent and don't hurt yourself in the process you are good to go. 
You have done this before. You'll do it again.